# AngularJS creating re-usable directives with variables

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a very simple Angular read-only directive:

```
angular.module('customDirectives', [])

.directive('ngAvatar', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<a href="#/people/?personId={{ entry.submitted_by }}">' +
                  '<img class="circular" ng-src="{{ entry.submitted_by | getAvatar }}" class="ng-cloak"/>' + 
                  '</a>',
    };
});
```

Now this works for the specific use case I initially wanted it for. But now I want to re-use it in any instance where I need to display a user's avatar and profile link.

As I start re-factoring my code, my html has this snippet which is the same except the variable names are different - e.g. {{ **comment**.submitted_by }}, {{ entry.**created_by** }}. These all occur with in an `ng-repeat` block where other information is also being displayed.

So, my question is, what is my best approach to making this directive re-usable and able to function with differently named variables? Should I rename my variables to be consistent (e.g. always use `entry`? Or is there some way I can extend my directive to take account of variables of different names, but of the same format.

Comment: You can get access to the scope that your directive is using by using the link function (link: function(scope, element, attrs){//dostuff};) but based on the re-usability you are looking for I would try and standardize your naming conventions.  It just ends up getting messy down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like what you want is to be able to pass in a scope variable to your directive. This is how I would do it. I haven't tested it, but I have done similar things many times.

```
angular.module('customDirectives', [])

.directive('ngAvatar', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { id: '=ngAvatar'},
        template: '<a href="#/people/?personId={{ id }}">' +
                      '<img class="circular" ng-src="{{ id | getAvatar }}" class="ng-cloak"/>' + 
                  '</a>'
    };
});
```

Then in your html you can pass in whatever the id is like this.

```
<div ng-avatar='entry.submitted_by'></div>
```